# How can I assert error values in ballerina?

Tags: unit-testing, error-handling, ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I have a error type as defined below,

```
type ErrorDetails record {|
    string message;
    string reason;
    "HIGH"|"MEDUIM"|"LOW" severity;
    int code;
    record {} other?;
|};

type Error error<ErrorDetails>;
```

I want to write a test function where I need to assert error values. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Ballerina test package, there are two methods named `assertExactEquals` and `assertEquals` which you can use to assert error values or any other value types.

- The `assertExactEquals` function will check whether the two values are exactly the same and check for reference equality (===).
- The `assertEquals` function will only check the values are equal.

The below example will help you to understand how this works.

```
import ballerina/test;

type ErrorDetails record {|
    string message;
    string reason;
    "HIGH"|"MEDUIM"|"LOW" severity;
    int code;
    record {} other?;
|};

type Error error<ErrorDetails>;

@test:Config
function testErrors(){
    Error actual1 = error("E1", message = "error1", reason = "casting", severity = "HIGH", code=12);
    Error actual2 = error("E1", message = "error1", reason = "casting", severity = "HIGH", code=12, other = {"a": 1});

    Error expected = error("E1", message = "error1", reason = "casting", severity = "HIGH", code=12);
    test:assertExactEquals(actual1, actual1);
    
    test:assertNotExactEquals(actual1, expected);

    test:assertEquals(actual1.detail(), expected.detail());

    test:assertNotEquals(actual2.detail(), expected.detail());
}
```

If you want to learn more about the Ballerina test framework please refer to this [link](https://pre-prod.ballerina.io/learn/test-ballerina-code/test-a-simple-function/).